# Django localization: how to create language file with msgstr = msgid

Tags: django, localization, translation

When I create language file with `django-admin makemessages -l` I need them to be their **msgstr** equals not empty string but its **msgid** by default. Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you need that? The effect is the same: if `msgstr == ""` the translation falls back to `msgid`

Comment: Actually no. When it were empty strings, values were taken from default language. Strange, no doubts

Comment: Ah, I see. For my projects, the default language happened to be the source language.